# Parsing YAML with Scala

Tags: scala, yaml

I have a simple YAML file, which is a map of maps:

```
top_level_1:
  entry_1: value_1
  entry_2: value_2
top_level_2:
  entry_3: value_3
  entry_4: value_4
```

How can I parse it to map of maps in Scala?

```
Map("top_level_1" -> Map("entry_1" -> "value_1",
                         "entry_2" -> "value_2"),
    "top_level_2" -> Map("entry_3" -> "value_3",
                         "entry_4" -> "value_4"))
```

Answer (score 3):

[SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) is a high-quality YAML library for Java. You can use it from Scala.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want to use a yaml parser that converts it into scala classes.
Look into using jackson with [scala module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) and [yaml dataformat module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/yaml).

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory()) with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

final case class YamlData(something: SomeYamlData, map: Map[String, String])
final case class SomeYamlData(field: String)
val myYamlData = mapper.readValue[YamlData](yaml)
```

Comment: Your solution will only work if you define case classes for each entry. Can we just get Map out of it?